# High load when Ethernet cable is unplugged

Tags: kernel, network-interface, ethernet, beagleboneblack, load

I'm building a system image with v4.19.106 kernel and BusyBox for BeagleBone Black using buildroot 2020.02. If I boot the board from the resulting SD card, I see a strange behaviour: system load stays between 0.60 and 0.75 while CPU usage is below 1%, with no services running, when there's no Ethernet cable connected. As soon as I plug in a cable, the load goes down to 0.00-0.01.

With the cable unplugged I see this line in `top -H`:

```
  PID USER         TIME+ S WCHAN      COMMAND
   42 root       0:03.03 D msleep     [kworker/0:3+events_power_efficient]
```

Snippet from `ip link` output:

```
4: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:3f:d3:91:f2:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Snippet from `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4C:3F:D3:91:F2:66
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:49
```

When I plug in the cable, I see this message:

```
# [ 3811.689083] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
```

After that there's no process with Process Status D in `top -H`, and the load goes down.

Snippet from `ip link` output with the cable plugged in:

```
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:3f:d3:91:f2:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Snippet from `ifconfig` output the cable plugged in:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4C:3F:D3:91:F2:66
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7605 (7.4 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:49
```

Unplugging the cable brings back the high load.

My eth0 config in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If I use `allow-hotplug eth0`, the interface stays down when the cable is unplugged at boot (and the load stays normal), but it doesn't come up afterwards when I connect a cable, just when I run `ifup eth0`.

How can I prevent the high load when a cable is unplugged, and get a working connection when it gets plugged in? Are there any kernel configs or device tree entries I should check?

---

Update:

The issue is present on an image built with the default configuration for the board ([beaglebone_defconfig](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2020.02/configs/beaglebone_defconfig)). It uses [v4.19.79-ti-r30 kernel from the beagleboard repo](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/tree/4.19.79-ti-r30) (with [omap2plus_defconfig](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.19.79-ti-r30/arch/arm/configs/omap2plus_defconfig)).

Another confusing bit is that the issue does not appear after every boot. Power cycling the board usually makes it appear if it was not present, while `reboot` not necessarily. (I'm not sure if it really makes a difference which method I use, or it just appeared so in my limited number of trials.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the SMSC LAN8710A PHY chip on BeagleBone Black. When it is put into power saving mode, it fails to detect if a cable has been connected. To work around this issue, the kernel driver regularly wakes the PHY chip to test for connection, and the details of this workaround have changed between v3.8.13-bone80 (used in [Debian 7.11](https://debian.beagleboard.org/images/rcn-ee.net/rootfs/bb.org/release/2016-06-15/console/bone-debian-7.11-console-armhf-2016-06-15-2gb.img.xz)) and the v4.4.9 (used in [Debian 8.4](https://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-8.4-iot-armhf-2016-05-13-4gb.img.xz)). The new method is still in use in Linux kernel v5.6.4.

The `msleep` function visible in `top -H` is called from `lan87xx_read_status()` in `drivers/net/phy/smsc.c`.

I resolved the issue by adding a node for the PHY chip to the device tree with a flag that disables the power saving mode:

```
&davinci_mdio {
    ethernetphy0: ethernet-phy@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        smsc,disable-energy-detect;
    };
};
```

(The `CONFIG_PM` kernel config option is ignored by the driver, this is the only way to disable this behaviour.)